# Symfony sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice displays id numbers instead of actual values

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I have a `user` table and an `article` table. When creating a new Article using Symfony's generated forms, the *User* dropdown/select shows numbers (user id numbers like 1, 2, 3...) instead of User Names.

I can obviously overwrite the form with a custom one in order to make sure this select element is populated with user names instead of their ID numbers, but I figured Symfony would have maybe already figured this one out and there was just something I was missing...

Should it show names by default or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it will call the model's __toString() method. You can override it in your models to return any string value.

```
class User extends BaseUser {
  public function __toString() {
    return $this->getUsername();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass the 'method' option to the choice widget. For example:

new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('Model' => 'User', 'method' => 'getUsername'))

Comment: where do I declare the `getUsername` method? In the form class?

Comment: If your model User has a column username, getUsername() will return that.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem myself. Basically if you have a table column called `name`, then Symfony will automatically use this field to populate a dropdown menu. I happen to be using `username`. Pretty cool design idea, but I don't remember reading it in the Symfony docs. Oh well.